# Trig:What's the graph of $\,\,\sin x .\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been googling the graph of $\,\,\sin x .\sin x$ to see a visual of a trig problem i'm working on:
$\sin^2x=\frac 14$ intervals $0$ to $2 \pi$.

you have to use this equation to solve: $\sin^2x=1/2[1+\cos(2a)]$

I got $3+2\pi/6$ but I'm pretty sure my answer is wrong.

Comment: Note that $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$. If you've made the typing error I think you have, the equation would then be $1-\cos^2 2x = \frac12 (1 + \cos 2x)$ which is a quadratic equation in $\cos 2x$.

Comment: I'm assuming (and my answer assumes) that you meant to solve $\sin^2(x) = \left.\left.\frac{1}{2}\right(1 + \cos(2x)\right)$.

Comment: you should try plotting graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zwqgjrmctt) to get clear idea

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that graphing is going to be helpful other than to check your solutions here.  You need to use a double angle formula and there are two routes to take.  The $\sin^2(x)$ looks similar to $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x) \rightarrow \sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2}$.  *Or* you can simply rewrite $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) = 1 - 2\sin^2(x)$.  Both will get you to the same solution but one will require you simplifying a $2x$ inside the trig function and one won't.  With that said, I think it's better to convert the $\cos(2x)$:

$$
\sin^2(x) = \left.\left.\frac{1}{2}\right(1 + 1 - 2\sin^2(x)\right) \\
2\sin^2(x) = 1 \\
\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} \\
\sin(x) = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

This is a special right triangle, the $45$-$45$-$90$ triangle.  We want both plus or minus so this is going to get every solution in each quadrant...very simple:

$$
x = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}
$$

...the other way to go about this is to transform the $\sin^2(x)$:

$$
\frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} = \left.\left.\frac{1}{2}\right(1 + \cos(2x)\right) \\
1 - \cos(2x) = 1 + \cos(2x) \\
\cos(2x) = 0
$$

The solution to $\cos(X) = 0$ is $X = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n$ (note there are two places, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, where $\cos(X) = 0$).  This gives:

$$
2x = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n \rightarrow x = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\pi}{2}n \\
x = \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}
$$

...the same solutions (as expected).

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=\frac12=\cos\frac\pi3$$

$$\implies2x=2m\pi\pm\frac\pi3\iff x=m\pi\pm\frac\pi6=\frac\pi6(6m\pm1)$$ where $m$ is any integer

We need  $$0\le\frac\pi6(6m\pm1)\le2\pi\iff0\le6m\pm1\le12$$

Consider $+,-$ signs one by one